# Are image subfolders allowed in Sigil?

Tags: epub, editing, sigil

I started out with InDesign. I was able to create a simple epub, then drag it onto eCanCrusher to crack open its contents. I could then copy images from another location into my epub and drag it back onto eCanCrusher, resulting in an epub filled with images - most of which were in subfolders.

Today I decided to give Sigil a try, and it's much easier to work with than InDesign. But I'm confused about the way it handles images.

If I create an epub with Sigil, then do the eCanCrusher routine, all images that are in subfolders vanish. If I copy fifty images into Sigil, the only remaining image is Cover.jpg, which isn't in a separate folder.

So my first question is: Can images be placed in subfolders in Sigil? If the answer is YES, then how do I do it?

Comment: What is eCanCrusher and what does it do? You have this problem after saving the epub file with Sigil, or after using eCanCrusher?

Comment: I learned about eCanCrusher via an ebook tutorial @ Lynda.com. You simply install the software and drag an icon onto your sidebar (on a Mac, at least). Then you can drag an epub onto the icon, and it creates an unzipped version that allows you to access the files. After modifying some files, you can then drag the folder back onto eCanCrusher, and it zips it into an epub again.

Comment: I can't remember exactly when the problem started. But if I'm not mistaken, you can't import folders into Sigil. If I choose File > Add > Existing Files, I can select an image to import, but if I select a folder, it's grayed out. Are you saying it IS possible to put folders inside the Images folder? If so, then I'll continue experimenting. But if it's physically impossible, then I'll just let it go.

Comment: Understood. I don't know how InDesign works, but you don't really need to use this tool with Sigil (or the similar Calibre editor); with those programs you open directly the epub file without the need to unzip it, you can make your edits and when you save the file you already have a working epub.

Comment: Yes, I can see all the files in Sigil. But there's still no way to directly copy and paste folders containing images into it, is there? The only way I know how to import images is File > Add > Existing Files. So I used eCanCrusher to "unzip" the epub I created with Sigil and paste images into it. But when I put it back together, the images vanish.

Answer (score 2):

After doing more research, I've learned that Calibre allows subfolders in the Images folder but Sigil doesn't. There are some suggestions that you can tweak Sigil to allow subfolders, but I haven't verified that it can be done.

https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=283132